# Windows command line tool for converting MP3 to AIFF and back

Tags: windows-7, command-line

Are there any Windows command line tools for converting MP3 files to AIFF (the standard iTunes format) and back?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[FFMPEG](http://ffmpeg.arrozcru.org/builds/) will do the job i think - it converts almost anything

Answer (score 0):

[VLC](http://www.videolan.org/doc/vlc-user-guide/en/ch04.html#id301635) has a fairly powerful command line interface.  You could use it to convert AIFF to MP3, but I don't believe it will write AIFF.  It still might be worth looking in to.