# Windows command line tool for MP3-AIFF

Tags: mp3

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Windows command line tool for converting MP3 to AIFF and back](https://superuser.com/questions/83079/windows-command-line-tool-for-converting-mp3-to-aiff-and-back)

Are there any Windows command-line tools for converting MP3 to AIFF and back? (AIFF), the standard format of iTunes (and most Apple products)?

Answer (score 3):

Try [FFmpeg](http://ffmpeg.org/):

```
ffmpeg -i Something.aiff -ac 1 -ar 22050 Something.mp3
```